# Finding the Exponential Fourier coefficients for $ f(t)=\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to find the Exponential Fourier coefficients for the following function
$$ f(t)=\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})$$

From the definition i get that

$$ c_k = \frac{1}{T}\int_{p}\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})e^{-ik{\Omega}t}dt $$

T in this case is $2\pi$ so i get that $\Omega = 1$ and

$$ c_k = \frac{1}{T}\int_{p}\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})e^{-ikt}dt $$

If i now use the fact that $ e^{-ikt} = \cos(kt) - i\sin(kt)$ i get that

$$c_k = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})\cos(kt) dt - \frac{i}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})\sin(kt) dt  $$

Since the integrand in the second integral is odd it should be $0$. Im now left with

$$c_k = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})\cos(kt) dt $$ and i cant seem to solve this integral. Moreover i have been told that you can find the Exponential Fourier coefficients for this function without solving any integral, but i can't see why. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\cos(t+\frac{\pi}{3})\sin(k t)$ is not odd

Comment: @jjagmath i figured since $\cos(t)$ is even that $\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})$ is aswell, but i guess that is wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong.

Comment: @jjagmath looking at the graph for $\cos(t + \frac{\pi}{3})$ i can now see that the function is neither odd nor even. It seems like the problem got somewhat harder for me since im now working with a harder integral than before.

Comment: $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and go from there. You don't need to integrate anything. As an exercise, try and then write down the real fourier series too.

Comment: @Paul Sorry if this is a stupid question but how come i don't need to integrate. I might have stared too long on the problem but if i write $ \cos(x + \frac{\pi}{3})$ with Euler's formula i still get something too hard for me to integrate. I suppose you mean that since $ \cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ i don't need to integrate at all, and i can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Angel has given you the full answer and called it a Hint for some reason. You can read off the complex fourier coefficients from that.